# How to disable the org.eclipse.jetty.server.error_page.global mapping to /error in Spring Boot with Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.3 with Jetty, I want to remove the error page handler altogether so it will fail fast in case of error, don't want to create the /error endpoint and don't want the /error routing failure with another 404..., I tried:

Using jettyServerCustomizer, it doesn't access the right properties.

Extending the WebServerFactoryCustomizer, it only adds error handlers but cant override the global handler.

Tried configuring via the application yml error section, you can't override the default /error configuration.

Tried overriding the ErrorPageCustomizer Bean... it is a private class with no conditions

What else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The "global error page" is a mandated Servlet 3.0+ behavior, you can't disable it, just configure it to be what you want it to be.

By default, the "global error page" location with a default installation of Jetty is undefined, meaning it will result in a default error page rendered by the `ErrorHandler`.

To configure the Servlet 3.0+ "global error page" you would define a web descriptor (in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`) to have an `error-page` entry without declared status code or exception.

The fact that you see "/error" is indicative that something on your environment is intentionally setting the "global error page" to that value.

Eg:

```xml
<!-- defined as servlet spec global error page -->
<error-page>
    <location>/global-error</location>
</error-page>
<!-- defined by response status code -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/generic-error-on-server</location>
</error-page>
<!-- defined by exception type -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
    <location>/error-in-io</location>
</error-page>
```

In embedded Jetty, the `WebAppContext` can be used to call `getErrorHandler()`, which will always at least be an `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler`, but can also be the more generally useful `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler`.

If you get the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler`, go ahead and call ...

```
ErrorPageErrorHandler errors = (ErrorPageErrorHandler) webappContext.getErrorHandler();
errors.addErrorPage(ErrorPageErrorHandler.GLOBAL_ERROR_PAGE, "/myglobalerror");
```

Again, note that you cannot set this to null or empty or any other variation of "i don't want it set" as that will still result in the default error page rendering and behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Joakim, the issue is indeed that it is spring boot that configures the /error, still as I am writing a microservice (no UI), I don't need this error page, more rever it returns the wrong HTTP error code if /error is missing and if I add the /error endpoint it causes a reundunt execution as this is a new filter chain inside jetty, and in my case it triggers also the security (oauth2) checking just for this navigation to /error... I just want a fail fast with no error page.

Comment: All services, even REST, need an error page.  Make sure that the error page returns an appropriate `Content-Type` response header and response body content based on the `Accept` headers in the request. (eg: a JSON formatted error)